# C pthread including header file and linking with -nolibc

Tags: c, symbols

This example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

__attribute__((weak)) int pthread_create( pthread_t*, const pthread_attr_t*,
    void*(*)(void*), void*);

int main()
{
    if (pthread_create)
    {
        printf("This is multi-thread version!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("This is single-thread version!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It says it is going to run in single thread mode if not linked to the pthread library but with the `#include pthread` isn't it going to be linked if compiled normally?
I think `pthread` is in `glibc` or `libc` but firstly is there a way to link excluding the standard library and if so when would you do that?
If there is code that can be run in multithread mode, is there ever any point in running it in single thread mode as in the example or is this just a bad example?  If so, what is a better example of hard-coding in something as a weak symbol?

Comment: "with the #include pthread isn't it going to be linked if compiled normally". No, not necessarily. Header files in general contain function prototypes but not the function definitions. Hence a function symbol only gets pulled in if the object containing the function definition is linked in during the build.

Comment: A preprocessor instruction to include some header into the C code is not related at all to the linker. If you want to link with some library, you must tell the linker. There is a common misconception that `pthread.h` or `stdio.h` might be libraries, which they are not.

Comment: pthread is not in libc. It is in libpthread.

Comment: `is this just a bad example?` Is opinion based. `If so, what is a better example of hard-coding in something as a weak symbol?` is also opinion based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but with the #include pthread isn't it going to be linked if compiled normally?

No, including a header file is different from linking with a library.

> I think pthread is in glibc or libc

It is not.

> is there a way to link excluding the standard library

Check your compiler documentation. `gcc` has [many link options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) like `-nolibc` `-nostdlib` `nodefaultlibs`.

> if so when would you do that?

When I am compiling for a bare-metal target that indeed has no C library. When I am writing my own standard library or I want to use a different C library then the default one distributed with the system or when crosscompiling I have a custom C library in a custom location and system doesn't ship one with the crosscompiler. Etc.

> If there is code that can be run in multithread mode, is there ever any point in running it in single thread mode`

Yes. For some reasons multithreading would results in worse performance when compared to single thread, like on a single core system. In case a realtime process that owns cpu anyway. Or in case a particular algorithm can't be multithreaded or would results in worse performance when multithreaded.